# Meaning of эмалер and полистывать

Tags: значения, глаголы

I can't find the meaning of the word 'эмалер' and the verb 'полистывать'.

Context:

> Виталий Петров (Праски ВИТТИ) обременен званиями, международными премиями и известностью среди многочисленных западных и немногочисленных российских **эмалеров**.

I think эмалер is derived from the German word Maler = painter?

> Выпускник Мухинского училища никогда не был диссидентом, но журналы соцсодружества и происхождения далее Берлинской стены, как всякий уважающий себя артстудент, начал **полистывать** еще во время учебы в Чебоксарском художественном училище.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer that helped you most as THE answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

No, `эмальер` (a word I wasn't aware of, and hence missed the typo; see Shady_arc's answer) is from `эмаль`, [enamel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitreous_enamel). *Maler* has entered Russian via Polish as `маляр`, and only means a non-artistic painter (one that paints fences, walls, etc.)

To `полистывать` is to occasionally `листать`. `По-`+root+`-ыва-` expresses irregularly repeated action, often with a suggestion of a leisurely attitude: `поглядывать` "to glance from time to time"; `помахивать хвостом` better describes the slow, one-wag-at-a-time action of a cat's tail as opposed to a dog’s more enthusiastic `махать хвостом`.

Answer (score 5):

There is a typo here, it should be "среди немногочисленных... **эмальеров**" from "эмальер". It somes from *эмаль*, which is "enamel". So the work mentioned here is actually about making enameled objects.

**полистывать** — from "листать" (to flip through pages). Such a construction sometimes makes a more cozy coloquial verb "to leisurely do the action once in a while, occasionally and without much work".

As for German "Maler", Russian «маляр» comes from it. But it means a construction worker who does painting (like, painting walls of a builiding)